# Reflect User Preferences in Design Time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, designer

When User changes form size and this is saved in Preferences, can the new size be applied in design time when the form is opened in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can the new size be applied in design time when the form is opened in Visual Studio?

No, not in any reasonable sort of way.

The Designer loads the design-time layout strictly from the `*.Designer.cs` or `*.xaml` file (for Winforms and WPF, respectively). While you can save and load the run-time size of the window (e.g. to the `Settings` object, the registry, a special file of your own construction, etc.), the initialization you put in the user code-behind (i.e. the regular `*.cs` file that goes with the form) will be ignored by the Designer.

You would have to modify the appropriate `*.Designer.cs` or `*.xaml` file itself. Not impossible, but IMHO impractical.

For what it's worth, I don't believe that it's a good idea to try to do this anyway. The window *should* be defined exclusively by changes made in the Designer itself. It's fine for the window's size to be retained from one instance of running the program itself to another, but for changes to the window's size in an instance of running the program to then be copied back to the design-time size of the window would mean that *every time* you tested the program, you ran the risk of deviating from the actual intended design of the window. Users resize windows for all sorts of reasons, and often these reasons don't apply at design time nor should be captured at design time to be reused the next time the program is run.